# Manipulate String in One Column and Append values to new rows in the DataFrame - Pandas

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas

I have data in a Pandas dataframe in the following format:

**Campaign       | Spend |**

L003-FL-Panama  | 800   |

L015, L020 CA- Rancho | 600   |

What I need  is to append each value from the Campaign column that starts with a capital 'L' and ends with three digits to a new column. To make matters more complicated, if there are multiple values in this format within a string in the campaign column, then I need each value to be listed in its own new row.

The output would be the following:

**Campaign       | Spend |  Store**

L003-FL-Panama  | 800   | L003

L015, L020 CA- Rancho | 600   | L015

L015, L020 CA- Rancho | 600   | L020

Apologies if this doesn't make sense, let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: Can you show us the code for your latest attempts, including it [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52083241/edit)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `extractall` then merge to the original dataframe

```
 df.reset_index().merge(df.Campaign.str.extractall('(\\bL\\d{3})').reset_index(),
           left_on='index',right_on  = 'level_0').drop(['index','level_0','match'],
           axis = 1).rename({0:'store'},axis = 1)

Out[65]: 
                 Campaign  Spend store
0         L003-FL-Panama     800  L003
1  L015, L020 CA- Rancho     600  L015
2  L015, L020 CA- Rancho     600  L020
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much